# Transparent UILabel textColor on superview.superview (sort of)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, uilabel

I would like to achieve the same effect as in the new iTunes remote update for iOS 7 for my `UILabel`.

If you look at this screen:

[image: http://313e5987718b346aaf83-f5e825270f29a84f7881423410384342.r78.cf1.rackcdn.com/1383617182-2013-11-05_03.05.58_04.png]

(The one on the right) you'll notice that the `UILabel` text color is the background blurred album cover without the black mask.

At the moment I have transparent `UILabel` textColor (http://cl.ly/SInK), my code is similar to https://github.com/robinsenior/RSMaskedLabel

My first assumption is to have a view hierarchy like that

```
UIImageView (Light blurred image)
    |
UIImageView/UIView (Dark blurred image or just a dark mask for the superview)
    |
UILabel (And all my other view).
```

I would like the `UILabel` to have a transparent text color on the first UIImageView, ignoring the second one/Mask).

I can't wrap my head around a solution to achieve this effect.

Comment: I want same functionality even i achieved it with OHAttributed label with some code of RSMaskedlabel . but i want to change color of that perticular text and after masking that i can't even change anything. you got any solution for this?

Comment: Post the code you've tried, the results so far, and how they fall short of what you want.  And keep it SSCCE:  http://sscce.org/

Comment: you want to set transparent background color to UILabel..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since iOS 8 Apple offer a new class, UIVibrancyEffect, which can be added to a UIVisualEffectView. This combined with a UIBlurEffect can achieve the exact same result as my screenshot above.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVibrancyEffect/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're going to be able to directly do this with a UILabel.  What I did was decompose it into several pieces:

How to draw only the background of a label.  For this I cribbed code from [CGPathRef from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976454/cgpathref-from-string) to turn the string into a path.  Then the subclassing UILabel and adding the following drawRect did the appropriate thing.

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef        ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

    // Convert the attributed text to a UIBezierPath
    CGPathRef           path = [self.attributedText createPath];

    // Adjust the path bounds horizontally as requested by the view
    CGRect              bounds = [self textRectForBounds:rect limitedToNumberOfLines:self.numberOfLines];
    CGAffineTransform   xform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(bounds.origin.x, bounds.origin.y);

    // Adjust the path bounds vertically because it doesn't seem to be taken into account yet
    bounds = CGPathGetBoundingBox(path);
    xform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(xform, 0., (self.bounds.size.height - bounds.size.height) / 2.);

    // Apply the transform to the path
    path = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(path, &xform);

    // Set colors, the fill color should be the background color because we're going
    //  to draw everything BUT the text, the text will be left clear.
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, self.textColor.CGColor);

    // Flip and offset things
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1., -1.);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0., 0. - self.bounds.size.height);

    // Invert the path
    CGContextAddRect(ctx, self.bounds);
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path);
    CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathEOFill);

    // Discard the path
    CFRelease(path);

    // Restore gstate
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
}
```

If you create a UILabel in interface builder, set the class, set the background color to clear and the foreground color to your proposed fill color, the background will show through where the text is.

To blur the body showing through the label, I dropped an FXBlurView (https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView) under the label with sizing constraints to keep them aligned.

You can see it all working here https://github.com/dwb357/TransparentLabel.

Answer (score 0):

The color is not uniform. But it's actually "cut out" to let the blurred and tinted background shine through.

One way to do it is to construct a CGPath for the glyphs, clip the graphics context to them, then clear the context, leaving the area outside black and the area inside fhe glyths translucent.

An alternative approach is to create a pattern color from this large blurred tinted cover art and use this pattern color on a UILabel.